# Cant load `PresentationFramework` after upgrade C# .Net 4.8 to .Net 5 (or 6)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

Using VS 2022 RC3 and SDK `6.0.0-rc.2.21501.6`

Project file already like

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

`Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF` framework is correctly referenced, version `6.0.0-rc.2.21501.6`

When I try to build the project I get a single error

```
Error   LC0000  'Could not load file or assembly 'PresentationFramework, 
Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its 
dependencies. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only
be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 
0x80131058)'    filename    filePathHere   LC   1
```

Comment: The package has been merged with the main .NET package, checkout the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/5.0/sdk-and-target-framework-change

Comment: You could try to use the following tool to migrate your code: https://github.com/dotnet/try-convert. Keep in mind that .NET 5 is cross-platform while .NET 4.8 is not, they are different beasts all together

Comment: `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>` is missing.

Comment: @HansPassant My bad, it's in there - updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was related to a `Telerik` file `Licenses.licx` which had references to .NET 4.7 components.